# How do I change the behaviour of logrus when it's used by third-party packages with vendoring?

Tags: logging, go

I am building a CLI app that imports and uses [github.com/docker/docker/pkg/proxy](https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/pkg/proxy).

The imported package uses a global instance of [logrus](https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus/) to log events, for example: https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/pkg/proxy/udp_proxy.go#L115

This causes logrus to send the events directly to my `stdout`, which pollutes my output.

I tried importing `github.com/Sirupsen/logrus` into my `main.go` and tried forcing the output to be discarded: `logrus.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)`.

However, that doesn't seem to have any effect on the output from the imported packages.

After some investigation, I noticed that the cause of the problem is vendoring. I have logrus installed in `github.com/me/myproject/vendor/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus`. The library I am using has logrus installed in `github.com/me/myproject/vendor/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus`.

I have created a test project and was able to reproduce this problem.

Is there anyway to control and configure logrus when it is used by third-party packages with vendoring?

Comment: It should work. Are you sure that the CLI app or any of the packages do not reconfigure logrus after your call `logrus.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)`?

Comment: @kostya: After some investigation, I discovered the problem is due to vendoring, so I updated my question. Is there anyway to work around that?

Comment: Just delete `github.com/me/myproject/vendor/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus` so there is only one copy of logrus package in yout app

Comment: @kostya, that works, but is less than ideal, as I am using glide to manage my dependencies. That's another question though. If you post your solution as an answer, I will accept it. :)